# Python - Generating the plural noun of a singular noun

Tags: python, nlp

How could I use NLTK module to write both the noun's singular and plural form, or tell it not to differentiate between singular and plural when searching a txt file for a word? Can I use NLTK to make the program case insensitive?

Answer (score 16):

You can do this by using `pattern.en`, not too sure about `NLTK`

```
>>> from pattern.en import pluralize, singularize
>>>  
>>> print pluralize('child') #children
>>> print singularize('wolves') #wolf
```

see [more](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en#pluralization)

Comment: awesome :) ... its probably worth noting youy also need `pip install pattern`

Comment: Thank you :) I surely will try this, but I still do nead NLTK for other uses.

Comment: You can import both. I couldn't find clean way of doing this in NLTK

Comment: What would it print if I tell it to print pluralize ('wives') or singularize ('child')? I mean is there any way to print the both forms of the word no matter which one I type?

Answer (score 6):

Pattern currently writing does not support Python 3 (although there is ongoing discussion about this here https://github.com/clips/pattern/issues/62.

TextBlob https://textblob.readthedocs.io is built on top of pattern and NLTK, and also includes the pluralization functionality. It seems to do a pretty good job of this, though it is not perfect. See the example code below.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
words = "cat dog child goose pants"
blob = TextBlob(words)
plurals = [word.pluralize() for word in blob.words]
print(plurals)
# >>> ['cats', 'dogs', 'children', 'geese', 'pantss']
```

Comment: I think the comment above should be updated to indicate that pattern now supports Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one possible way to do it with NLTK. Imagine you're searching for the word 'feature':

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
text = "This is a small text, a very small text with no interesting features."
tokens = [token.lower() for token in word_tokenize(text)]
lemmatized_words = [wnl.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens]
'feature' in lemmatized_words
```

Case sensitivity was dealt with using `str.lower()` in all words, and of course you also have to lemmatize the search word if necessary.

Comment: Can I add the .lower() directly to the raw_input(' > ') ?

Comment: Yes, you can do `raw_input('> ').lower()`.

Comment: Great. So if I add .lower() will it accept the word however I type it? Like Admin admin aDmin admiN and so?

Comment: It will transform all those forms into 'admin', yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me :)

Answer (score 3):

It might be a bit late to answer but just in case someone is still looking for something similar:

There's [inflect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect) (also available in [github](https://github.com/pwdyson/inflect.py)) which support python 2.x and 3.x.
You can find the singular or plural form of a given word:

```
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()

words = "cat dog child goose pants"
print([p.plural(word) for word in words.split(' ')])
# ['cats', 'dogs', 'children', 'geese', 'pant']
```

Is worth noticing that `p.plural` of a plural will give you the singular 
  form.
  In addition, you can provide a POS (Part Of Speech) tag or to provide a number and the lib determines if it needs to be plural or singular:

```
p.plural('cat', 4)   # cats
p.plural('cat', 1)   # cat
# but also...
p.plural('cat', 0)   # cats
```

Comment: Strange. `inflect.engine().plural('children')` outputs `'childrens'`... Why?

Comment: Yes, this library has some strange behavior in some cases, another one:
`inflect.engine().plural('houses')` outputs `'housess'`

I'm not fully aware of the internals, I'm actually going my self through it these days.

There are some very well working cases but also some mistakes that look pretty obvious

Answer (score 0):

I have tried following code tweaking inflect library, hope it will help you.

```
import inflect

inflectEngine = inflect.engine()

def getSingular(word):
    return word if not inflectEngine.singular_noun(word) else inflectEngine.singular_noun(word)


def getPlural(word):
    word = getSingular(word)
    return word if not inflectEngine.plural_noun(word) else inflectEngine.plural_noun(word)

########################################################
##################### Testing Area #####################
######################## Output ########################

# UNCONDITIONALLY FORM THE PLURAL
singularWord1 = "dog"
singularWord2 = "horse"
singularWord3 = "terretory"
pluralWord1 = "books"
pluralWord2 = "hotels"
pluralWord3 = "categories"

print("The plural/singular conversion : ", singularWord1, " => ", inflectEngine.plural(singularWord1))
print("The plural/singular conversion : ", singularWord2, " => ", inflectEngine.plural(singularWord2))
print("The plural/singular conversion : ", singularWord3, " => ", inflectEngine.plural(singularWord3))
print("The plural/singular conversion : ", pluralWord1, " => ", inflectEngine.plural(pluralWord1))
print("The plural/singular conversion : ", pluralWord2, " => ", inflectEngine.plural(pluralWord2))
print("The plural/singular conversion : ", pluralWord3, " => ", inflectEngine.plural(pluralWord3))
print("")

######################## Output ########################
# The plural/singular conversion :  dog  =>  dogs
# The plural/singular conversion :  horse  =>  horses
# The plural/singular conversion :  terretory  =>  terretories
# The plural/singular conversion :  books  =>  book
# The plural/singular conversion :  hotels  =>  hotel
# The plural/singular conversion :  categories  =>  category 
#########################################################

print("The singular conversion")
print(getSingular(singularWord1))
print(getSingular(singularWord2))
print(getSingular(singularWord3))
print(getSingular(pluralWord1))
print(getSingular(pluralWord2))
print(getSingular(pluralWord3))
print("")

######################## Output ########################
# The singular conversion
# dog
# horse
# terretory
# book
# hotel
# category
#########################################################

print("The plural conversion")
print(getPlural(singularWord1))
print(getPlural(singularWord2))
print(getPlural(singularWord3))
print(getPlural(pluralWord1))
print(getPlural(pluralWord2))
print(getPlural(pluralWord3))
print("")

######################## Output ########################
# The plural conversion
# dogs
# horses
# terretories
# books
# hotels
# categories
#########################################################

# CONDITIONALLY FORM THE PLURAL
count = 1
print("I saw", count, inflectEngine.plural(singularWord1, count))

count = 5
print("I saw", count, inflectEngine.plural(singularWord1, count))

######################## Output ########################
# I saw 1 dog
# I saw 5 dogs
#########################################################
```